# Run PowerShell FUNCTION as administrator from Batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting

I have a PowerShell script. The way I usually execute this script in the PS console is by using:

```
. .\psScript.ps1

functionName
```

`functionName` is my entry function. I am attempting to run this PowerShell script and auto execute the function `functionName` as Administrator from a batch file. I can execute this script and function from my batch file using:

```
powershell -command "& { . .\psScript.ps1; functionName }"
```

However, this does not execute the script as administrator. So I have also tried the following:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "". .\psScript.ps1; functionName""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

This still does not work, and the console disappears too quickly for me to read the error message. Could anybody please help?

Comment: I assume that cmd is not launched as admin?

Comment: Cmd is not launched as admin, no.

Answer (score 2):

This works, from a non-elevated command prompt:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell –Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ""-File C:\Path\To\Script\psScript.ps1"""
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does run the script as admin from a non-elevated cmd prompt, however, it does not auto-execute the function I need it to, I.e. functionName (shown above)

Comment: Easiest way to run the function, is to wrap dot-sourcing of the the `psScript.ps1` file AND the function call into a *second* script. Then call that *second* script using my method above .

Comment: @potatopotarto you could add a call to the function at the end of the ps1 file, i.e. at the top you have `function a { ... }` and then after that just type `a` to call it.

Comment: @TechSpud How would I wrap the dot source script. Would it be something along the lines of . ". \psScript.ps1" functionName ?

Comment: @potatopotarto - Yes. Line1: `. C:\path\to\script.ps1`. Line2: `functionName -param1 value1 -param2 value2`